# Screenshot windows mobile from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

is possible take screenshot of wm device from visual studio 2008?
I use this function on eclipse with android....but for visual studio?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's in your Remote Tools, it's called **Remote Zoom In**.  It's available from your Start Menu, down under `All Programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 -> Visual Studio Remote Tools`